# Bootstrapping hybrid applications manually

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, angular-upgrade

How to bootstrap this angularjs 1 app from Angular 6 manually?

As a starting point I have a working angularjs 1 app: f.e. [image: Angular1 ui-router Helloworld] and a pure angular 6 app created with angular-cli.

First step is adding the necessary dependencies like angular, @uirouter/angularjs, @angular/upgrade, @types/angular to package.json, and filling the scripts part in the angular.cli:

```js
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/angular/angular.min.js",
    "node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.min.js",
    "app/app.js"
]
```

Then I put the angular 1 app to /app/script.js and to /index.html

I removed the `<body ng-app="helloApp">` from index.html so the modified index.html looks like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="hello-app">
        <div ng-controller="HelloController">
            <a ui-sref="hello" ui-sref-active="active">Hello</a>
            <a ui-sref="about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a>
            <ui-view></ui-view>
        </div>
    </div>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

To bootstrap the angular 1 from angular 2 I added the ngDoBootstrap() to app.module.ts and I removed the bootstrap[AppModule] part:

```js
import {
    BrowserModule
} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
    NgModule
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    AppComponent
} from './app.component';
import {
    UpgradeModule
} from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        UpgradeModule
    ],
    providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) {}
    ngDoBootstrap() {
        this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.getElementById('hello-app'), ['helloApp'], {
            strictDi: true
        });
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working. I'm getting the error message:

> "ERROR Error: "[$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=%24%24UpgradeModule&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr..."

Is anything wrong with this concept?

Comment: can u use `angular.js` file rather than `angular.min.js` and share a readable `error` message than the one which u have shared

Answer (score 0):

After changing the angular.min.js to angular.min the error message is visible:

ERROR Error: "[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module $$UpgradeModule due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module helloApp due to:
[$injector:strictdi] function($stateProvider) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

Using the explicit annotation solved the problem:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi